# JS hex string to actual byte values of a file

Tags: javascript, file-io, hexdump

I have this array called data and at each index there's a byte's worth of hex strings, it looks like this

```
var data = new Array("0A", "31", "55", "AA", "FF")
```

If i inspect the file in a hex editor I should expect to see that sequence. So if I want to write a file so that the values starting at memory address 0x00000000 is that sequence of hex values, how would I go about that?

currently I'm creating the downloadable files with this code.

```
function download(filename, text) {
   var file = document.createElement('a');
   file.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
   file.setAttribute('download', filename);
   file.click();
}
```

Comment: your question does not help anyone understand what do you really need, tell more things

Comment: Array of bytes I want to be written to a file so I can download said file.

Comment: with the second code snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some hex numbers as strings without the prefix, and you want to write them as bytes to a file. Because there are currently no byte implementations in javascript, you will have to convert each byte to its corresponding char and then write to your file.

```
var data = new Array("0A", "31", "55", "AA", "FF"), file = "";

//turn hex string to number, then convert it to string and append to file
file += data.map(hex => String.fromCharCode(+("0x"+hex))).join("")

//byte file back to hex array
data = file.split("").map(ch => ("0"+ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2))
```

Comment: This still has nothing to do with byte-level file writing. All your example does is turn a string into another string.

Comment: javascript has not byte variables, but there is an approach with strings. if you want to do byte level writing here, you must first turn the letters you want into byte string as i show you above, then make your byte changes and then return it to actual letters and write file. If you want real byte level file writing you should consider c c++ node.js and other languages that are made for this kind of things.